# How to declare and initialize Arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to initalize `Arrays` using a for-loop. But I can't cast or covert an `int` to `Arrays`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class InitalizeArrays {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 5, 8}; //this one is fine            
        Arrays[] arr2 = new Arrays[5];

        for(int i=0; i<=arr2.length; i++)
        {
            arr2[i]=i;   //How to initalize Arrays 
            System.out.println(arr2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you want arr2 to contain?

Comment: @Paul, i want to initalize it with some value.......

Comment: If you want to fill it with numbers it should be an int[] just like arr. I don't understand why you've made it an Arrays[].

Comment: ok Paul. i think you are correct. one more question. why i am able to create object here for Aarrays[] with size 5.

Comment: i got whole scenario now.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays` is not an object that you should be using... it is just a set of helper methods for dealing with arrays (note the lower-case "a").  Here's the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Arrays in an object, because it extends Object class. public class Arrays
extends Object. But i cannot see constructer for this as per document. so looks like we cannot intialize it.

Comment: I never said it wasn't an object... I said it is "not an object that you should be using".  It just contains static helper methods for dealing with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Valid indices of an array are `0` to `array.length - 1` (and it's an array of `int`s (not [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) - a utility class). You need to change

```
Arrays[] arr2 = new Arrays[5];
for(int i=0; i<=arr2.length; i++)
```

to something like

```
int[] arr2 = new int[5]; // <-- to store an int.
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) // <-- or arr2.length - 1
{
    arr2[i]=arr[i]; // <-- to copy arr.
}
```

**or** maybe you want to use [`Arrays.copyOf(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) like

```
int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
// no for loop to copy needed.
```

Comment: That will be run time exception, say ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. i am facing here compile time error.

Comment: The compile exception is because an `int` is not an instance of the utility class `Arrays`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays[] arr2 = new Arrays[5];
```

should be replaced by

```
int[] arr2 = new int[5];
```

That's all.

Sure there won't be any compile time error but there will be runtime error
because Java won't treat Arrays[] like int[] arrays.
It will be treated as another data type with NO relation to integer arrays.